# if there exists a smooth map $M\rightarrow N$ and a smooth map $N\rightarrow M$ then $M,N$ are diffeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M,N\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be smooth manifolds. Suppose there exists smooth maps $f:\ M\longrightarrow N$ and $g:\ N\longrightarrow M$ such that $f,g$ are bijective.

Here we only have the smoothness of the forward direction for each map. My query is if $M,N$ are diffeomorphic, which means there exists a bijection $h:\ M\longrightarrow N$ that’s smooth in  both directions? If it’s not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Exotic 7-dimensional spheres will serve as counter-examples.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, in this case $M$ and $N$ are indeed diffomorphic.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan what are the smooth bijective morphisms ?

Comment: I mean if M can transform into N smoothly by some map f, and the same for N by some map g, then is it indeed that M and N are diffeomorphic ?

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike may you explain why exotic 7-dimensional spheres is a counter-example ?

Comment: @PermQi: It is nontrivial as it requires one to understand the construction of exotic 7-dimensional spheres, more precisely, that every such sphere admits a Morse function with two critical points. Whenever $M_1, M_2$ are smooth compact connected $n$-manifolds admitting such Morse functions, there is a smooth bijection $M_1\to M_2$. Once the strike is over, I will write a proper answer, unless somebody else does it before.